# Unable to extend MonoBehaviour class, "The name does not exist in the current context" Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, extension-methods

I have a class that inherits MonoBehaviour. Extension methods for GameObject work, but not for MonoBehaviour.

Class File

```
namespace UnityEngine
{
    public class Test : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private void Start()
        {
            TestMono();
            gameObject.TestObject();
        }
    }
}
```

Extension File

```
namespace UnityEngine
{
    public static class MonoBehaviourExt
    {
        public static void TestObject(this GameObject obj) {}
        public static void TestMono(this MonoBehaviour obj) {}
    }
}
```

In the Start() method, the TestMono() method is underlined with a red line and the error says "The name 'TestMono' does not exist in the current context.".

From what I understand, in C# it is impossible to prevent class extensions, and I can not see where my error is.

Comment: weird but try this.TestMono

Comment: this.TestMono worked! Can you post it as in answer? I wonder why it doesnt work without this though.

Comment: As an aside, don't use `namespace UnityEngine`. If you're going to use a namespace, use your own namespace.

Comment: yea i posted it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `this.TestMono()` to make it work.